# AEM: How to list all pages in a fixed directory (JSP)?

Tags: jsp, aem, sightly

I want to list all the pages that exist in the directory /content/abc

I only care about the pages that exist exactly in this directory (nothing in deeper sub-folders, no child pages, etc).

Could someone help provide me with the JSP code I might use to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `listChildren()` method of the [Resource](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html) class to list all resources under that directory. Iterate them and check if the resource is a Page.

```
Resource parentResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/abc");

Iterator<Resource> resources = parentResource.listChildren();
while (resources.hasNext()) {
        Resource res = resources.next();
        if (res.adaptTo(Page.class) != null) {
            //it's a page. Do stuff with this
        }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Your code is wrong. It would list all the child resources and not just the pages. Whereas, question mentions that you need only the pages that exist in the directory.

Comment: But /content/abc is not a page, so the Iterator<Page> call will fail.

Comment: Yes. It would fail in that case. You would need to iterate the resources and then check if they can be adapted to a Page. Then you would get the pages under that directory

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I said. Thanks, though. You got me on the right track :) (AEM noob)

Comment: Updated the answer for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Is that directory also a page? 
If so, you could use the Page API for that and Page#listChildren(), something along the lines of:

```
Page thePage = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);
if (thePage == null) {
    //not a page, fail
    return;
}
for(Iterator<Page> children = thePage.listChildren(); children.hasNext();) {
    Page child = children.next();
    // do something
}
```

If the directory is not a page then you should be good with rakhi4110's answer